# Sending HTML email from Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to send HTML email via python on a unix server. I need to use p.communicate for other reasons. I'd like not to change this code too much so I dont have to fix all the scripts that use this function.

What I am trying to do is send to multiple to_add. it works with one but not more. I've tring to_address as a list, a string with addresses separated by comma.

```
html = MIMEText("<html><body>"+content+"</body>", "html")
msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
msg['To'] =  email.utils.formataddr(('Recipient', to_address))
msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('Author', 'author@company'))
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.attach(html)
p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-f","author@company","-t"], stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(msg.as_string())
```

works with

"myemail@mail.com"

doesnt work with

"colleague1@company.com,colleague2@company.com"
["colleague1@company.com","colleague2@company.com"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating your addresses with a space, not a comma. Alternatively you can just pass the list of addresses directly to the `/usr/sbin/sendmail` call (and omit them from the `MIMEMultipart` structure):

```
email_addresses = ["foo@bar.com", "baz@far.com"]
p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail",
           "-f", "author@company.com",
           ",".join(email_addresses)] , stdin=PIPE)
```

Comment: The `-t` option to Sendmail should be omitted in the alternative scenario.

Comment: @tripleee - Whoops, I happened to be a victim of copy/pasta :(. Good catch!